# How to correctly fetch git notes with zsh?

Tags: git, zsh, git-fetch

Recently vagrant image i use switched to zsh and i can't get git notes from remote with it. I try:

```
git fetch origin refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
```

And get:

```
zsh: no matches found: refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
```

What is the correct command then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zsh sees the asterisks in your command, thinks its a glob and tries to expand it, but there are no files that match the pattern, so it fails. If you wrap the argument in single quotes, it won't try to expand the glob and the argument will be passed as expected:

```
git fetch origin 'refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*'
```

Comment: Or to make zsh behave like bash, use `setopt nonomatch`. Zsh's default behaviour is cleaner, however. In the case of git, I'd recommend doing `alias git='noglob git'` because it is rare to need it with globs and it can do it's own globbing in cases where you would want it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your command makes sense (I'm not sure of that), it's possible that the colon in `refs/notes/:refs/notes/` is being interpreted as ending a device name, or something odd. Try put single quotes around that parameter, to stop zsh trying to "understand" it.

```
git fetch origin 'refs/notes/:refs/notes/'
```